# How to shift a plot so that the label in the y-axis is not cut?

Tags: python

this is a part of a whole program in python where my concern lies. The graph is too big that the label in the y-axis is "cropped-out". Any suggestions?

[cropped photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HHYb.png)

```
# ======== 3 log-log Fsq1 with error bars VS time ==============        
    plt.xlim([1,500])
    plt.xlabel(r'$t$', fontsize=8)
    plt.ylabel(r'$log F_s(q1, x(t))$', fontsize=8)
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.yscale('log')
    
    plt.errorbar(time , Fsq1, Fsq1err, color='r', label= r'Numeric', linewidth=1)
    plt.plot( time , Fsq1num, 'c-',label= r'Theory', linewidth=1)

    plt.legend(loc=4)
    #plt.show()
    pdf.savefig()
    plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try plt.tight_layout()

This adjusts spacing to avoid cropping out parts of the figure. It's not perfect, so you may want to play around with the parameters. See [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html)